# Does the mammoth rider's gigantic steed ability affect the space occupied by his animal companion, and other unmentioned modifiers?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, prestige-class, animal-companions, creature-size

The [mammoth rider](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/i-m/mammoth-rider) prestige class is the only class in the game that allows to have a Huge animal companion. The ability is described as follows :

> Gigantic Steed (Ex)
>
> A mammoth rider's steed increases to Huge size. The creature receives
>   a –1 penalty on attack rolls and to AC, and a –2 penalty to Dexterity
>   (to a minimum of 1); its base damage increases by one size category;
>   and its reach increases to 10 feet. It also gains a +2 size bonus to
>   its Strength and Constitution. At 3rd level and every two levels
>   thereafter, the Strength bonus increases by an additional +2; the
>   bonus to Constitution increases by an additional +2 at 5th and again
>   at 9th level.

The mammoth rider has a limited list of animal companions available, all of them being Large at the point when this class is available to the player, then it's globally an increase by one size category with some ability score modifiers added.

[According to the main rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/space-reach-threatened-area-templates), enlarging a creature from Large to Huge would increase its natural attack damage by one step, its reach by 5 ft, its CMB and CMD by 1 and its occupied space from 10x10 ft to 15x15 ft, reduce its AC by 1 and give extra penalties to attack rolls (-1), Fly checks (-2) and Stealth checks (-4).

In the case of Gigantic Steed, the penalty to attack rolls and AC, the extra reach and increase in natural attack damage are mentioned but nothing else is. ***Does this mean that Gigantic Steed only affects those numbers and everything else remains the same, including the creature's occupied space ?***

Answer (score 2):

They're just trying to simplify changing your Animal Companion there, it's getting all the effects of moving from Large to Huge though.

- It's getting a -1 to attack and AC because Large have a -1 already and Huge has a -2.
- Increasing by a size category increases by two die steps, not one. [Source](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/enlarge-person). Look at the FAQ on the right to see how you should change the damage of your creature.
- It's reach goes to 10 ft. as a Huge from 5 ft. as a Large, considering they are long and not tall.

All the other rules for being Huge would still apply with the statement that you're increasing their size to Huge as they never said anything otherwise. They were just trying to keep it simple by putting most of the effects of the changes in one area at once.

So, yeah your companion gets all the effects of being huge not just the ones listed by the RAW of that paragraph and also probably by the RAI too.

This was my first answer since I made my account yesterday, hope it was helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was really wondering since a few creatures break the general rules, and the exceptions generally override the rules. For example, the Juggernaut is a Gargantuan construct with a reach of 5 ft (since it uses rollers), or the war bull, a Huge quadruped with a reach of 15 ft (justified by its massive horns and the fact that it's described as bigger than its actual occupied space)

Comment: Yeah, unless its specifically stated though you can assume it's normal rules. Since with this it never says "except" or anything else that would point out that this is special rules, it's normal.

Comment: RAW those changes are in *addition* to the normal changes for changing size.  You change the size to Huge (and do all the stuff that means, like changing the space it occupies), and then *also* apply the various stat modifiers mentioned.  This is, of course, silly.